# wake up, unfreeze or restart local KDE session from remote ssh

Tags: linux, manjaro, kde-plasma-5

My PC (Manjaro Linux, kernel 6.1.62-1) has a bad habit, which is that after it falls asleep, and I'm trying to wake it up by wiggling the mouse, the monitor gets no signal.

The mouse and keyboard are connected through the monitor, and their respective LEDs light up, but that's as far as I get locally.

I am however able to log in from my laptop, using ssh, and it seems as if a few things have crashed badly:

```bash
[user@pc ~]$ ps -ef |grep plasma
user      2602    2375  0 10:28 ?        00:01:03 [plasmashell] <defunct>
user      3799    3421  0 10:29 ?        00:00:00 [plasma-browser-]
user      7759    7698  0 17:05 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --colour=auto plasma
[user@pc ~]$ ps -ef |grep kde
root         161       2  0 10:27 ?        00:00:00 [kdevtmpfs]
user      2494    2375  0 10:28 ?        00:00:00 [kded5] <defunct>
user      2666    2375  0 10:28 ?        00:00:00 [polkit-kde-auth] <defunct>
user      2812    2375  0 10:28 ?        00:00:00 [kdeconnectd] <defunct>
user      2872    2375  0 10:28 ?        00:00:00 [msm_kde_notifie]
user      7763    7698  0 17:06 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --colour=auto kde
```

So, plasmashell seems to have crashed ... While I'm of course interested in avoiding that sort of thing next time, this question is mostly about how I can restart all the processes necessary to start a new session on the PC, from a remote ssh connection.

And because I've seen this being misunderstood in too many other questions: I *do not* want to get a remote graphical desktop session, just put the machine in a state where I can log in normally, locally, without rebooting it, by means of a remote ssh session.

I tried to kill the `<defunct>` processes but they just keep going.
Process 2375, which seems to be the one that launched all of them, is `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user`-- not sure if it is wise to kill it.
Since this is not the first time I'm in this situation (and possibly not the last one, either), I know that I can kill systemd, with user permissions, but it requires the `-9' flag, since asking nicely won't help. That gets rid of the other defunct processes, but does not get the PC to talk to the monitor again. CTRL+ALT+F2 and so also don't seem to do anything, although it's hard to tell since the monitor has a tendency to give up quickly and go into power saving mode itself.

So far, the best "solution" is to just `shutdown -r now`, which reboots the machine, but I'd much rather just reset the desktop session (assuming I can't save it) than reboot the whole machine, since there may be things running in the background that I'd prefer to keep running.